# Is there a free Office App for the iOS to read Word, Excel, PowerPoint & OneNote files?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, ms-office

I've looked around the AppStore for this but have not found one yet. Maybe my keywords are all messed up. Is there an app that will allow me to read files created by Microsoft Office on the iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has an official OneNote for iOS on the App Store. It was free for a limited time when I got it. It is still buggy, but should get better as it is the official app. As far as the other Office file types, I know of an app called Documents To Go. I cannot officially recommend it since I do not own it. I just know it's out there and that it supposedly allows you to open and edit Office files. You may want to check it out.

I do agree with David's answer in that if you just need to open these files, Dropbox is a very decent solution. I use Dropbox to open files I create at home using Pages and Numbers (I do not use Office, but if I did I would still use Dropbox to open the files I had created on my iPhone). Dropbox will not allow you to edit the files, but to quickly open while on-the-go it is a very good solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the Documents 2 Go suggestion. There is a free version that's good enough

Comment: This week Apple released Numbers, Pages and Keynote for iPhone. They were previously available for Mac and iPad only. Now you can create and edit documents made in these apps right on your iPhone. No sure they'll work with Microsoft Office file formats but still worth a look if you're open to ditching Office altogether.

Answer (score 1):

These can be displayed by IOS with no software involved, other than OneNote.  The trick is getting the files onto the device.  Email is one way; you can view these files, other than OneNote, as attachments, using the ioS Mail app.

Another alternative is to use a sync service client (e.g. dropbox) to access the files.

Comment: Accepted. But is there an app? I'm willing to take no for an answer if there isn't. With iOS 4, you can easily move files from machine to device app (eg: VLC app to play vids); so if there's an app, I'd like that.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to buy an "Office editing" app such as Documents to Go; these should let sync via iTunes.  However, this will probably cost you $10 or so and have clunkier syncing than just getting a free Dropbox account and using their iOS app as the viewer.  For your purposes, I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sky drive account so that I can access One Note anywhere including my desktop and on my iPad.  I put the skydrive app on my ipad and then uploaded the spreadsheet I needed to access on the go.  Not a perfect solution, but one that will work in a pinch when away from my desktop.